# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException

Tags: java, android, gradle

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

I searched all the similar questions and solutions, but they do not help. I hope experts like you come up.

The project code has been uploaded into bitbucket: https://tainule@bitbucket.org/tainule/numad-huizhang.git

**I have two modules, app and endpoint. Below is from Module:app:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "edu.neu.madcourse.huizhang1"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 3
        versionName "2.1"
//        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
}

dependencies {


    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.2'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.4-beta1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4-beta1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4-beta1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
    compile project(path: ':endpoint', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
    compile files('src/main/res/libs/KeyValueAPI.jar')

}
```

**Below is from Module endpoint:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.17'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.8'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.8'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.8'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:4.0b3'
    compile 'com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2'
//        compile 'com.github.fengdai:alertdialogpro-theme-material:0.1.0'

}

appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
    endpoints {
        getClientLibsOnBuild = true
        getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to at least give us some background if there is to be any chance of assistance

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your reply. the possible reason may be that I add a external library module --endpoints. This is all I know. and the code have been uploaded to bitbucket , could you please help me with it ?https://tainule@bitbucket.org/tainule/numad-huizhang.git

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code (specifically your build.gradle) file here, as part of your question.

Comment: I did. Thanks for your help,Yole.

Comment: i also got same error please help give some suggestions to solve it.am not uploading to any bitbuket or other.

Comment: can also try this one. compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

Comment: I found this Git discussion helpful for me: https://github.com/facebook/rebound/issues/71

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem by changing compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0 ' to compile 'com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0'

Comment: That's probably due to the mentioned method limit. The older version of Guava probably had less methods in it. Enabling multidex fixes this issue for real.

Comment: in my case I already using "com.google.guava:guava:17.0" but problem is same.

Answer (score 82):

It seems you have a jar file or a lib appearing multiple times.

So, remove the .jar file from the lib folder then:

`Build` > `Rebuild`

Comment: That's great, and it makes sense in my case, because we mistakenly check in the content of `app/build` to SVN, and that screwed up our builds locally.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on AS 1.5 It rebuilds succesfully but I try to run it I get the same error as in the question above :(

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':ReliantApp:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Answer (score 45):

I had the same problem error that is shown, i solve it by adding

```
defaultConfig {        
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

I had this problem cause i exceeded the 65K methods dex limit imposed by Android i used so many libraries

Comment: this answer should marked as correct one. After trying all above issues this one worked for me. I know it must be bad solution but one who is using multiple android libraries he will face this issue and this solution will work for him/her. as those libraries use v4 or v7 support libraries. So in your project it repeats the library more than 1.

Comment: This worked for me, its the only solution which worked out of all the solutions.

All other users check all other solutions, in case they does not work than this will surely work.

Comment: hi, where do i add this in?

Comment: inside build.gradle file of your app module put it inside the android { ... }

Comment: thanks a lot! definitely this should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 20):

I am adding it so that someone in a similar situation might find it helpful.

So, even after `multiDexEnabled = true` I was getting the same error. I had no *duplicate libraries*. None of the above solutions worked. Upon reading the error log, I found `OutOfMemError` issue to be the primary reason and thought of changing the `heap size` somehow. Hence, this -

```
dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

Where "4g" means `HeapSize` of 4 GB. And it worked! I hope it does for you too.

Comment: After adding this, I had to take out multiDexEnabled for mine to finally work.

Comment: so your app runs without multiDex enabled?

Comment: yes, if I add multiDex enabled, I get some errors I haven't had time to look into further. I'm going take it for now, thanks for the tip.

Comment: THANK YOU! I'm working on this problem for a whole day. But I only add javaMaxHeapSize "4g" to gradle and it works.

Answer (score 15):

For me I had multiple versions of the same library included in `/app/libs`. I was using Parse and I had both `ParseFacebookUtilsV3-1.9.0.jar` and `ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.0.jar`.

Deleting the `V3` jar solves the problem.

Comment: I had the same issue, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

three condition may cause this issue.

1. differ module have differ jar
2. in libs had contain jar，but in src alse add relevant source
3. gradle repeat contain，eg:

   compile fileTree(include: [‘*.jar’], dir: ‘libs’)

   compile files(‘libs/xxx.jar’)

if you can read chinese ,read here[Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: o](http://blog.csdn.net/u011570979/article/details/46519329)

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same exact error message. I am not quite sure if my solution will solve also your issue.

In Project Structure (app) I changed the Compile SDK Version from API 22 to API 21 and changed Build Tools Version from 22.0.0 to 21.1.2.

When I downloaded the latest API 22 Adroid 5.1, every project I create is using this API and causes me the problem. Maybe, Android Team is looking for a fix for this one.

Answer (score 6):

I've got this problem after including same classes twice

Answer (score 4):

I recently migrated one of our corporate projects from Eclipse to Android Studio.

We too got the below error during the migration:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':appName:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

To resolve it, we had to do a few things:

1. Remove/Update duplicate jars/files from libs

> compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23'     compile
>   'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'

to `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'`

2. Set multiDexEnabled to True

> defaultConfig {    multiDexEnabled true }

3. Increase the heap size:

> dexOptions {
>           incremental true
>           javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
>       }

Answer (score 3):

This could also be the case when you have too many object references. Take a look at the results from the build, esp in the task :dex:multiDebug:

trouble writing output: Too many method references: 67114; max is 65536.

Answer (score 2):

Try to put this line of code in your main projects gradle script:

```
configurations { all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4' }
```

I have two libraries linked to my project and they where using 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Yep, this is a pretty bad solution (sorry for it). Although, I found another solution. There was a need to include RecyclerView into my project and it needed the support-v4 library. So I had to manually exclude support-v4 lib from all the dependency project and add it in my main gradle script (use gradle to list you the dependencies so you can see what else uses the support-v4 lib)

Answer (score 2):

I solved the same issue by removing:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

and adding for each jar file:

```
compile files('libs/yourjarfile.jar')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try  to clean  and rebuild the project. I had the absolutely same question, this solved it.

Comment: Can you please tell how to clean ionic project using windows command?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and solved by change the '+' to a exact number, like compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+" to compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0".

This works for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I changed :

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'`

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'`

to :

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'`

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'`

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue when converting an eclipse project to Android studio.In my case i had the design lirary jar file in eclipse project and I have added dependency of the same in gradle caused the error.I solved it by deleting jar from libs.