# Build Java ver error on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am hoping someone could shed some light on the following build error I get when trying to launch a project in Android Studio just imported form Eclipse:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':dIveApp:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

I am running on OS X Yosemite 10.10 and running java 8.0 Update 60 (build 1.8.8_60-b27). the url above seems to reference jdk1.7.0_11jdk, not sure if this is the issue or how to check.

Cheers

Comment: I guess your import is not prefect  and do not expect it to be so. You will have to trouble shoot it one step at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Look at gradle console log, most probably you will see an exact error.

Most of the time this is because you added the same package few times - library for different modules or in different places.
If not - try to clean - rebuild project.

p.s. You can change JDK for project in File -> Project Structure

Also, there is already answers for this question
[Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917696/)

Comment: Thanks, couldn't find in duplicate jars or Libarys so just deleted project, will start again