# Android studio error while running the code

Tags: android

I am getting an error in Android studio while running the code, its not giving the exact info what is the issue, from where I can see the exact info of the issue caused. I struck up at this since long time.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':eAMSRNAMTrunk:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

I did not find any duplicate jars still I am getting the issue, is there any way that Android studio says exact error in logs, in eclipse will get the exact error.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':pdf417ScanActivity')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/date4j.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.2.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/imagezoom.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
}
```

Comment: Does your project have any dependencies ? dexDebug happened when I included unnecessary libraries in the build path. Make sure you have set up your dependencies correctly.

Comment: Take a look at [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917696/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-com-android-ide-common-process)

Comment: Added my gradle file I did not see any duplicate libs but still I am getting error..