# Gradle build slow after adding symja and log4j-1.2.11 to Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, symja

I have tried this:

Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tool > Gradle

and check Offline work checkbox in Global Gradle settings.

however this does not seem to make any difference.

Edit- I have just added --stacktrace to compiler option
`

```
            apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

            android {
                compileSdkVersion 21
                buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

                defaultConfig {
                    applicationId "com.hr.hrproductions.mathapptake5"
                    minSdkVersion 21
                    targetSdkVersion 21
                    versionCode 1
                    versionName "1.0"
                }
                buildTypes {
                    release {
                        minifyEnabled false
                        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                    }
                }
            }

            dependencies {
                compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
                compile files('libs/WolframAlpha-1.1.jar')
                compile files('libs/commons-math3-3.5.jar')
                compile files('libs/log4j-1.2.11.jar')
                compile files('libs/symja-2015-09-26.jar')
            }`
                FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

            * What went wrong:
            Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
            > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3

            * Try:
            Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
                            * Exception is:
            org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
                    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
                    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
                    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
                    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
                    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
                    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
                    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
                    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
                    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
                    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:310)
                    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
                    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
                    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
                    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.ParallelTaskPlanExecutor.process(ParallelTaskPlanExecutor.java:45)
                    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
                    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
                    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
                    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
                    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
                    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
                    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
                    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
                    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
                    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
                    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
                    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:54)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:49)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
                    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
                    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
                    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
                    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
            Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
                    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:116)
                    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor$waitForTasksWithQuickFail$0.call(Unknown Source)
                    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PreDex.taskAction(PreDex.groovy:114)
                    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
                    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:243)
                    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
                    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:230)
                    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:208)
                    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
                    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
                    ... 57 more
            Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
                    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:42)
                    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.preDexLibrary(AndroidBuilder.java:1387)
                    at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.PreDexCache.preDexLibrary(PreDexCache.java:122)
                    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.preDexLibrary(AndroidBuilder.java:1330)
                    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder$preDexLibrary$3.call(Unknown Source)
                    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PreDex$PreDexTask.call(PreDex.groovy:158)
                    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PreDex$PreDexTask.call(PreDex.groovy)
            Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
                    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:365)
                    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:40)
                    ... 6 more


            BUILD FAILED

            Total time: 2 mins 33.602 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this question [Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28917696/24819) it may be, that you use a jar file or a lib appearing multiple times in your Gradle script?

Symjas 2015-09-26 development JAR is using the latests commons-math 4 internally in it's JAR. This may not match with your commons-math 3 dependency.

Try to reduce to the libraries which are absolutely necessary.

I've used the following [SymjaDroid libraries](https://bitbucket.org/axelclk/symjadroid/src/master/SymjaDroid/libs/) in my latest android reference app:

```
COMMONS_MATH4_SYMJA.jar
jsr305.jar
log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.2.jar  
slf4j-android-1.6.1-RC1.jar
symja-2015-10-03.jar
```

Comment: I tried removing my current modules and replacing them with the ones you have used in you android reference app, however it appears to be an issue with the symja-xxxx-xx-xx.jar files I add as when I remove it from my build file every thing seems to work perfectly.