# Android Studio - Adding JsonPath dependecy causes error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, jsonpath

I am creating an app where I need to use JsonPath. However, when I add it to my dependencies I get the following error from my gradle build:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

I have researched this problem for two days now, but nothing seems to work. Adding `multiDexEnabled true` to my build.gradle file gives me this error instead:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/objectweb/asm/AnnotationVisitor.class

I've also tried adding `mavenCentral()` and `maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }` to my repositories as well as deleting the intermidiates folder, but nothing works.

The exact dependency is `'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.2.0'`, but I've also tried different versions. I've previously added a few maven libraries without a problem.

Does anyone have any clue what may be my problem?

Comment: Someone else has had the same issue; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33353508 - no accepted answers unfortunately