# How to integrate facebook login in android app using SocialAuth

Tags: android, socialauth

I'm working on facebook integration using socialauth I've added socialauth jars but couldn't execute the program it's showing the following error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I don't know why is it showing that, I might not have installed libraries properly.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile files('libs/socialauth-4.4.jar')
compile files('libs/socialauth-android-3.2.jar')


}
```

Please help Thank you in advance

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-add-facebook-login-to-your-android-app--cms-23837 go through from this link this worked for me...

Comment: Thanx for the response but this is the traditional way.. i've done integration using facebook SDK but now I need to integrate facebook, twitter and login that's why I'm using **SocialAuth**  But stuck due to this error

Comment: For twitter u can use twitter4j lib.

Comment: but using that approach i will have to install new libraries each time for new integration whereas socialauth supports **fb,twitter,linkedin,googleplus,myspace,flicker,instagram etc.**

Comment: Then check once in library folder you may have added same library twice or not

Comment: I've added there two different libraries of social auth

Comment: that's what i'm thinking but those are two different libraries

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917696/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-com-android-ide-common-process

Comment: oh, come on ... It is obvious: look at the first dependency and last two dependencies ...

Comment: Now i've resolved the previous problem. Now On click of button logcat says :  
org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthError: URL Authentication error