# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebugAndroidTest'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException

Tags: android, testing, spock

here is my [full code](https://github.com/roroco/vst/tree/cannot-run-spock-on-adr), when I run following code with "Run/Debug configurations > Android Tests"

```
class KernelTest extends Specification {
    def "match"() {
        given:
        println("smth");
    }
}
```

I get error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk8/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
```

here is [full output](https://gist.github.com/roroco/21dd7f75396f101a6fcb)

how to fix it?

**update**

I have check [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917696/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-com-android-ide-common-process), but I don't know which jar is duplicated

Answer (score 0):

See the full output, the reason is about groovy, I remove all groovy dependencies and work well