# Gradle build error in Android Project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting following build error

Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

[build --debug](https://gist.github.com/kuldeepiitg/dcddf20925106b305b07)

[build --stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/kuldeepiitg/9125e744067592cb6f0f)

[build --info](https://gist.github.com/kuldeepiitg/3d5cca5702033f5a9f59)

Comment: try building with jdk 1.7 insted of 1.8

Comment: Could you show a more complete error by running your gradle build with the "--debug" flag?

Comment: Use gradlew assemble --info to get more details and post here

Comment: @DougStevenson added links for logs, pls have a look

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti please check the links for logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the --debug log.  There is a very verbose error description starting with the text:

trouble processing "javax/transaction/HeuristicCommitException.class":

> Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) when
>   not building a core library.
>
> This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file in
>   your application's project, when using an IDE (such as Eclipse). If
>   you are sure you're not intentionally defining a core class, then this
>   is the most likely explanation of what's going on.

I think the bottom line is that you shouldn't be including libraries that contain classes defined in java.* or javax.*.  You'll have to trim down your dependencies. Android development can not normally handle J2EE type code.

Comment: thanks a lot, I got the root cause. I have a local maven dependency which uses J2EE library.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try cleaning your project.
2. If that doesn't works then:
   Try adding `multiDexEnabled true` to your app **build.gradle** file

Comment: @Kuldeep See this link - "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917696/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-com-android-ide-common-process" and see if any of the solution helps you.

Comment: @samjhol I think I have some different problem

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
dexOptions {
            preDexLibraries = false
            additionalParameters=['--core-library']
}
```

In you app level gradel inside android..It will work 100%

Comment: No such property: additionalParameters for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DexOptions_Decorated