# Error->Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, android

I am getting this error when I am using rebuild the app it finished successfully but when i am using the run app it shows this error. I am not getting any relevant answer. Please help me for

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:createDebugMainDexClassList'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: post your app level build.gradle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917696/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-com-android-ide-common-process)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change android `buildToolsVersion` according to android `compileSdkVersion` 
if `yourcompileSdkVersion` is **23** then set
    **buildToolsVersion to 23.0.1 or 23.0.2** try this hope this solve your problem.

Comment: This looks like an answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

At first you go to

```
Build -> Clean Project
```

and then go to

```
Build -> Rebuild Project
```

if its not work then check this

```
defaultConfig {        
// Enabling multidex support.
multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update Your JDK from 1.7 to 1.8, JDK 1.8 is recommended for Android Studio and also it improves functionality.

**Check this link for Execution Fail** - [Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917696/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-com-android-ide-common-process)

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.It worked for me.

First enable

```
defaultConfig {
 multiDexEnabled true
 }
```

Include in your app level build.gradle dependencies this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

then in your Manifest add name of the application as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="----<your package>-----">
<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    ...
</application>
</manifest>
```