# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When I try to run my app on my phone I get the following error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

I am relatively new to programming so from doing some research this could be because duplicate libraries or exceeding memory. So I have tried several suggested options like removing this line from dependencies

> compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

also adding adding these to the build.gradle(app) file

> defaultConfig {
>      ...
>      ...
>      multiDexEnabled true
>   }

and

> dexOptions {
>           preDexLibraries = false
>           javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
>       }

Gradle syncs just fine, problem is when I try to run on phone. I can run other apps in Android Studio just fine, just this particular one. If there is duplicate of libraries, how do I check and which ones are?

The gradle file is as below

> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myweb.MyApp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'

```
/*Added*/
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.3'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
```

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

and gradle console log

> Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCustomtabs2321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk4110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFirebaseuiFirebaseUi043Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFirebaseuiFirebaseUiAuth043Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFirebaseuiFirebaseUiDatabase043Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth921Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase921Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuth921Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthCommon921Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthModule921Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCore940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabase940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabaseConnection940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\app\google-services.json
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzaga;","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:579)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:535)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:517)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","sources":[{}]}

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.719 secs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out, actually the problem was caused by

> compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'

which i have removed since its an old library,
and I think is a duplicate of

> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'

which is the new library since Firebase changed as per point 3 of [this article](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android)

changed to this:

> ```
> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
> compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.4'
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Running

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean
```

from the root directory solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have duplicate **jar/libraries** in your project.
**Changed your gradle file from:**

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.3'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
```

**To like this:**

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
```

Also check any other jar/library duplication in your project.

Comment: Also check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917696/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-com-android-ide-common-process

Comment: I played around with the libraries and it was actually caused by "compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'" which i removed and it worked