# How to fix "Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:"?

Tags: java, android, build.gradle

I keep getting this error every time I build my gradle.

Here's my app.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.devteam.abire.abire"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

heres my project gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I've been getting this error for the past three projects I have made. It is very annoying. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please also add console log of the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917696/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-com-android-ide-common-process)

Comment: Will do. @AtefHares